# How to fix ScriptImporterEditor.OnInspectorGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine

"ScriptImporterEditor.OnInspectorGUI must call ApplyRevertGUI to avoid unexpected behaviour."
This error appears in every new project.
It's her fault that scripts aren't drawn in the inspector.
The error itself appears after switching the cursor from a folder to any script.
There is also a similar error "ScriptImporterEditor.OnInspectorGUI must call ApplyRevertGUI to avoid unexpected behavior.", which breaks the display of sprites.

What it should look like

[image]

What does it look like

[image]

What I have already tried to do:

1. Update the editor version to LTS (from 22.3.5f1 to 22.3.20f1)
2. Create a new project
3. Reinstall the editor version

Has anyone encountered this problem and was it somehow solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-importing all the files in the project. I get this error ALL the time and the only way I was able to fix it was by re-importing the files. Do this:

```
Assets > Reimport all
```

Comment: It got a little better, but when switching from a folder to a script or texture, the problem continued to appear

Comment: Yeah, that happens. When you do that, try to rename a file in the folder. And, when you make a script, rename it. That should fix it. Plus, of you rename the script make sure to edit the script's namespace